# How to get and show all the data recovered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-hooks

I have some datas, who I can get my data when I'm in the loop. But, if I set the data in a useState array value, I just have the last value.

How to get and show all the data in the render ?

My code out :

```js
const [messagesList, setMessagesList] = useState([])
```

My code at useEffect :

```js
firebase.database().ref(`accounts/${username}/messages/`).on('value', (snapshot) => {
            const jsonData = snapshot.toJSON()
            const keys = Object.keys(jsonData)

            const finalData = keys.map(key => {
                const element = jsonData[key]

                for (const i in element) {
                    const elementFinal = element[i]

                    setMessagesList([elementFinal])
                }
            })
})
```

My code at render :

```js
{messagesList.map((x, i) => (
                <div key={i}>
                    <p key={i}>{x.senderUsername} said "{x.message}"</p>
                </div>
            ))}
```

My Firebase database :

[image]

My result :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are erasing the value of messageList. Let say, elementFinal equals '45'

```
setMessagesList([elementFinal])
```

will result in

```
messagesList // ['45']
```

You need to read the previous value (the shallow copy is important) and set the new one:

```
const array = [...messagesList];
array.push(elementFinal);
setMessagesList(array)
```

EDIT: I didnt see that it could be reduced as follow:

```
const messages = [];
 const finalData = keys.map(key => {
                const element = jsonData[key]

                for (const i in element) {
                    messages.push(element[i]);
                }
            })
setMessagesList(messages);
```

Comment: Thanks so much ! I knowed I just have the last, but I wasn't know how to get the rest. Thanks really much 